# What is the simplest way to check if user is authenticated in Feathers hook without raising error?

Tags: feathersjs

This question was already answered here: [Hook to check if user is authenticate in Feathers (without send Unauthorized error if not, just check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830738/hook-to-check-if-user-is-authenticate-in-feathers-without-send-unauthorized-err)
But supplied answer does not work for all cases.

Looks like that in Feathers v4 there is no more `allowUnauthenticated` option, as it was in v3:

```
  authenticate('jwt', {
    allowUnauthenticated: true
  })
```

But v4 [anonymous authentication](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/anonymous.html) strategy does not work when you send an expired token.

If you configure hooks this way:

```
all: [ allowAnonymous(), authenticate('jwt', 'anonymous') ],
```

Anonymous strategy will not work if you send expired token and `authenticate('jwt', 'anonymous')` hook will respond with unauthorized error.